# Batch suppress "Connection to host lost"

Tags: batch, telnet

I am using the BOFH server to get random excuses, however whenever it runs it states "Connection to Host Lost" after it has run, since the server immediately disconnects (expected behavior). How can I supress this message?

Running `telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl 666 2>nul` does nothing.

And the following script does not output anything:

```
set num=0    
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl 666') do (
    set /a num+=1
    echo %%A
    if "!num!"=="3" exit /b

)
```

Comment: Is there is `head` on windows?

Comment: Yes it has a head display

Comment: The command `head` that shows only the first n lines of output ...

Comment: What? I don’t understand what you’re trying to say. Maybe say it in your natural language?

Comment: @EugenRieck no, `head` doesn't exist on Windows.

Comment: @MarkDeven have you tried redirecting error output to NUL? `for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl 666 ^2>NUL') ...`

Comment: Yes. Whenever I tried using NUL it either changes nothing or redirects all output.